# Faceting on a faceted field in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a collection of documents like:

```
{
  myTime : <a date_time>,
  myVal : <a number>
}
```

I would like to know the maximum hourly average of that number. So basically i would like to have hourly buckets each with its average value of `myVal`, and then find the maximum value for that average.

I tried using Json Faceting like the following, but of course it doesn't work, complaining about `avgMyVal` not being a known field:

```
json.facet={
  maxAvgMyVal : "max(avgMyVal)",
  tempi: {
    type: range,
    field: myTime,
    start: "NOW-7DAYS",
    end: "NOW",
    gap: "%2B1HOUR",
    facet: {
      avgMyVal: "avg(myVal)"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get solr to do this? Or am I missing something?

Using Solr 7.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do this in one request, but you can at least do it with two separate requests (or one request if you don't mind the sorting).

You can [sort the facets by the value returned by your `avg` function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/json-facet-api.html#sorting-facets-by-nested-functions) and retrieve the first value:

```
sort: "avgMyVal desc"
```

.. inside your `tempi` definition. If you need to have the result sorted by the intervals in `tempi`, you can either sort it for display after retrieve it, or make two queries - use `limit: 1` to retrieve the largest value in `avgMyVal`.

Comment: It seems that sorting is ignored by range facets. I can put anything inside the sort field (non existent fields also) and still get the same response. I'm using Solr 7.2.1. Toes sorting works for you in range facets?

Comment: Hm. good point. Could you add a few example documents to your post and I'll try to look at it when I get some spare time tomorrow unless another answer has surfaced until then.

Comment: Let's say i have several documents as simple as this:
{
  "myTime": "2019-07-02T12:52:42.072Z",
  "myVal": 50
}
Just need to put some random dates and values.